# Pass variable from batch to powershell

Tags: batch-file, powershell

I have a batch file that ask the user for a variable line `set /p asset=`. Im calling my powershell script like this

> `SET ThisScriptsDirectory=%~dp0`
>
> `SET PowerShellScriptPath=%ThisScriptsDirectory%file.ps`
>
> `PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& '%PowerShellScriptPath%'";`

Im wondering how i send powershell the variable 'asset' from my batch file.

Here is my .bat file content

```
@Echo off  
cls
Color E
cls

@echo Enter asset below
set /p asset=

@echo.
@echo your asset is %asset%
@echo.
goto startusmt

:startusmt
@echo.
@echo executing psexec ...
@echo.

SET ThisScriptsDirectory=%~dp0
SET PowerShellScriptPath=%ThisScriptsDirectory%RemoteUSMT.ps1
PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -file %PowerShellScriptPath% %asset%
psexec \\%asset% -u domain\username -p password cmd 

goto EOF

:EOF 
PAUSE
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have a `file.ps1` that takes a parameter,

```
param($asset)
"The asset tag is $asset"
```

You can pass in the variable as an argument.

```
SET ThisScriptsDirectory=%~dp0
SET PowerShellScriptPath=%ThisScriptsDirectory%file.ps1
SET /p asset=Enter the asset name

PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -file "%PowerShellScriptPath%" "%asset%"
```

Comment: File runs the PowerShell script. You can use `-file` in place of calling the file from `-command`.

Comment: `PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -file "%PowerShellScriptPath%" %asset%` Like this?

Comment: How do I reference that variable in powershell?

Comment: In the example that I gave, the value of `%asset%` is passed to the `$FileName` variable. You can use whatever variable name you want; the point is that the arguments listed in the batch file get passed to the  param variables in the .ps1 script. If your .ps1 took two parameters (e.g. `param($one, $two); write-host "one: $one, two: $two"`) you could call it from a batch file with `PowerShell -file %PowerShellScriptPath% %assetA% %assetB%`

Comment: This is what I have right now and the powershell line wont display my variable asset when I try to call it. bath file line is `PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -file %PowerShellScriptPath% %asset%`  Then in my .ps file I have
`param($asset)`  `Get-Item $asset`  `"The asset tag is $asset"` . But the script never puts the asset I typed in the .bat file

Comment: @rangerr You don't want `Get-Item $asset` in your PowerShell script. I only used it as an example in my script.

Comment: even with the `Get-Item $asset` left out im still not able to have the $asset in powershell to to the %asset% I defined in the .bat file.

Comment: Have you tried the example exactly as it is in my answer? It works for me. Maybe you are doing something differently in your bat file.

Comment: my .ps file only has your 2 lines plus `"The asset tag is $asset`. my .bat file looks like my first post but with your edit to the powershell line

Comment: The PowerShell script should be .ps1 not .ps

Comment: Sorry yes its called "RemoteUSMT.ps1" and in side its `param($asset)` and `"The asset tag is $asset`

Comment: Hmm, that batch file works for me; I see 'the asset tag is <text I entered>'. Are you seeing PowerShell only outputting: "the asset tag is "?

Comment: Yes its only saying "the asset tag is " and not inputting the $asset variable

Comment: I'll post an answer below with my batch file content if that helps

Comment: I tried the .bat text from your updated post and it worked for me, so I'm stumped as to why it's not working. You may want to put quotes around both variables on the powershell call in the batch file in case there is a space in the path or the user's input, but I don't think that is the problem if powershell outputs something. Have you tried @wmz`s answer? It would be interesting to hear if that works. Just make `"The asset tag is " + $env:asset` the only line in your .ps1 file.

Comment: That work. Im not sure why that way works and the other way doesnt but at least it works now. Thank you for helping me figure this out!

Comment: @Rynant What if I'm calling powershell like this: `powershell -Command "Remove-Item %filePath%\* -Recurse -Exclude '*.avi','*.mkv','*.mp4'"`? I.e. not using a script, but simply invoking a single command? This doesn't seem to work for me :-/ I've also tried wrapping the command in braces like so `&{command}`, separating the command into its own batch variable, using `setlocal` and all sorts of weird hacks, but no dice. This seems to be such a simple thing to do but really isn't for a batch and powershell n00b like me!

Answer (score 5):

You can use `$env:variable_name` syntax to access curent cmd environment variables from powershell. To get hold of your variable you'd use `$env:asset`
To try, open `cmd`, do `set "myvar=my value"`, start `powershell`, do `$env:myvar` (this will simply print it, but of course you can use it as any other ps variable)

Just as a sidenote, ps has good help system. If you  do `help env` it will list two relevant topics which you can examine in turn to get detailed information.

Hope this helps

Comment: Yes this is an option, but generally it's better to have arguments that you pass in to the PS script so that you can tell by the function signature what the script depends on for input. It also makes the PowerShell script more usable if calling directly from PowerShell.

Comment: @Rynant Generally yes, but sometime somewhere you may find you have control over the script but not it's invocation/environment and then it comes in handy :-)

Answer (score -1):

```
param($asset)
```

This has to be the very first line in the PowerShell script for it to work, else it will fail.

Comment: Your answer repeats information from the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23157149/45375), while providing nothing new.