# Create a cmd prompt for a URL then set that URL as $URL in a powershell script

Tags: powershell, batch-file

Using a series of scripts to build a signage PC that opens Chrome and displays a specific URL. I have been manually setting the URL withing the powershell script that opens Chrome and displays the page. Since a batch is used to do some setting up of the unit, I'd like to set the $URL variable in the PS1 via a prompt during the setup bat.

I have tried a few things from other threads with no luck. I have little experience with batch or powershell. Not a task I was given but figured it may be nice to improve what I have been given as the current standard procedure.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23156707/pass-variable-from-batch-to-powershell would that be what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, the best way to transfer info from Batch to PowerShell is to use environment variables.

For example, if you have a PowerShell script named MyPowerShellScript.ps1, having the following content:

```
$URL = $Env:URL
Write-Host "[URL=$URL]"
```

And call it with the following batch file:

```
@ECHO OFF
REM As per mklement0's comment, SETLOCAL limits environment changes to batch file
SETLOCAL
SET "URL=https://stackoverflow.com/"
PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -file MyPowerShellScript.ps1
```

Will give this output:

```
[URL=https://stackoverflow.com/]
```

Comment: `setlocal` is need for `.cmd` files too (just tried it), so I don't think the extension matters here. You definitely want this to be an _explicit_ feature, otherwise you wouldn't be able to set process-level environment variables.